# Ubuntu Efi disk read & boot error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios

I have fujitsu lifebook. Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via USB. It works well but, the problem is I can't boot from other installation media anymore. When I try to boot from a CD or USB I see:

```
Secureboot is not enabled.
error: efi disk read error.
```

Then Ubuntu starts. Also, when I try to open BIOS I get the same error message above and BIOS doesn't appear, Ubuntu starts. I need to install windows but, because of this problem I can't. In addition, I tried boot repair but it couldn't find

> grub-efi-amd64

Comment: What do you mean "you can't boot"? If Ubuntu starts, you are booting. How did you try bot repair? From Ubuntu? What command? What was the exact error message? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: I mean I can't install windows 7 via usb nor cd. Also, as I said I can't enter Bios. It just doesn't enter

Comment: OK, so you can't boot from a CD or USB right? You can still boot OK from the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I can't install different OS and I need Windows. Somehow, bios is blocked and I can't enter it because of the problem above.